# Can a convex lens form a real image of a virtual object?

Tags: optics, visible-light, lenses

What is a virtual image? How is a real image formed from a virtual object in the case of a convex lens?

Comment: A real image can be cast onto another surface. This is basically what you're doing when frying ants with a magnifying glass: you're casting a virtual image of the sun onto the and, and the light is so intense that the ant burns up. A virtual image can only be seen by looking through the lens. As far as I know there's no such thing as a virtual object.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

*What is virtual image*

A magnifying glass produces a virtual image.

[image]

Every point on an image has a one to one correspondence to a point on the object and has the same neighbouring points with a one to one correspondence with the object.

Fir the magnifying glass the rays emerge divergent but appear to come from a localised region (the virtual image) on the other side of the lens.

Those divergent rays are then focussed by the optical system of the eye into a real image on the retina of the eye.
Considering the optical system of the eye the virtual image produced by the magnifying glass is a real object as that optical system of the eye cannot differentiate between the arrangement as shown in the diagram and having no magnifying glass present and a real object placed at the position of the virtual image and of the same size as the virtual image.

*How a real image is formed from virtual object in the case of convex lens?*

Consider a convex lens $L_1$ producing a real image $I_{\rm R1}$ of a real object $O_{\rm R1}$ as shown in the left-hand diagram.

[image]

Interpose a convex lens $L_2$ between lens $L_1$ and the real image $I_{\rm R1}$ that it formed when lens $L_2$ was not there.

For lens $L_2$ that real image which lens $L_1$ formed can now be considered as a virtual object $O_{\rm V2}$ forming a real image $I_{\rm R2}$ as shown in the right-hand diagram.